# Intercalate columns when they are in pairs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using this table:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |

In Google Sheets if I do this here in column E:

={A1:B3;C1:D3}

Teremos:

| E | F |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 9 | 10 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 7 | 8 |
| 11 | 12 |

But the result I want is this:

| E | F |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 |
| 9 | 10 |
| 11 | 12 |

I tried multiple options with `FLATTEN`, but none of them returned what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can try:

```
=WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:D3),2)
```

- 

[image]

Comment: When i use ```=WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:D3),2)``` i receive ```Unknown function: "WRAPROWS".``` → My Google Sheets is in English

Comment: Now i receive ```Formula parsing error.```

Comment: oops... sorry then:(

Comment: Could it be that these functions are not available for general use?

Comment: maybe they are still in rolling out phase. you could probably save it for the future;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try with MAKEARRAY

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(A1:D3)*2,2,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(FLATTEN(A1:D3),c+(r-1)*2)))
```

[image]

### GENERAL ANSWER

For you or anyone else: to do something similar but with a variable number of columns of origin or of destination, you can use this formula. Changing the range and amount of columns at the end of LAMBDA:

```
=LAMBDA(range,cols,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(range)*ROUNDUP(COLUMNS(range)/cols),cols,LAMBDA(r,c,IFERROR(INDEX(FLATTEN(range),c+(r-1)*cols)))))(A1:D3,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
={FLATTEN({A1:A3, C1:C3}), FLATTEN({B1:B3, D1:D3})}
```

[image]

for more columns, it could be automated with MOD